# Responsive grid with "expanding" items

Tags: html, css

I have a grid of list items where most of them are hyperlinks, but a few of the items cause a row below to appear when clicked on revealing sub-items.
I've been attempting to make the grid responsive, such that when the screen width becomes small, the grid becomes a single column of items. However I cannot maintain the expansion for both layouts.

An example of how this works for the full sized grid can be seen at: https://jsfiddle.net/au6bq6hj/

The HTML I'm using for the grid is:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="main">
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">1.0</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">2.0</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);">2.1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);">2.2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">3.0</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">4.0</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The following images detail what I'm attempting to do. The first image is the full width grid before expansion, and the second image is this grid expanded. The third image is the single column list before expansion, and the fourth image is this but with item 2.0 expanded to reveal 2.1 and 2.2.

When I have the media query to make the items full width, my method for showing the hidden row doesn't work.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, I think I might have cornered my thinking and can't see what to do next.

[image: Full width grid before expansion]
[image: Full width grid after expansion]
[image: Single column before expansion]
[image: Single column after expansion]

Comment: I wrote a little patchup library for a case like this. You might be able to adapt it to your needs http://jsfiddle.net/mdibbets/5r5A5/

Answer (score 0):

You could write media query to make your `li` tags' width be responsive.

In this case, let's say you want the list to be single column when the screen goes under 400px. Then here is what I'm going to add at the end of your code:

```
 @media (max-width:400px) {
li{width:90%;}

}
```

Hope this will be helpful to your project.

Comment: Thank you for that, I accidentally left out the media query in my example code. The issue with this is that the items become covered after expansion in the single column layout.